# How to replace strings in matching column?

Tags: bash, awk

suppose here is the file

```
abc,def,ghi 
1,a,zeta
2,b,beta
3,c,ceta
4,d,xaq
5,gh,lpa
```

Above is just an example but in real there are many columns and I need to replace column strings (e.g having heading name "def" to NA) where header matches.
Expected output is

```
abc,def,ghi 
1,NA,zeta
2,NA,beta
3,NA,ceta
4,NA,xaq
5,NA,lpa
```

I am able to print only column where header name "def" with below command

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/def/)f[n++]=i}{for(i=0;i<n;i++)printf"%s%s",i?" ":"",$f[i];print""}' /tmp/test
```

But is there a way to print with modification and all the content of text file ONLY using AWK?
Note: Its is not confirmed that always it will be 2nd column

Answer (score 8):

Using `Miller`:

```
$ mlr --csv put '$def = "NA"' file
```

With `-I`, the changes are made "in-place", modifying the original file without outputting anything to the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v col='def' '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==1 { for (n=1; n<=NF; n++) if ($n == col) break }
    NR>1  { $n = "NA" }
    { print }
' file
abc,def,ghi
1,NA,zeta
2,NA,beta
3,NA,ceta
4,NA,xaq
5,NA,lpa
```

The above assumes you WILL have a column name match, if you might not then add some defensive code like `NR>1 && n { $n = "NA" }`.

By the way, to print only the target column you'd change `NR>1 { $n = "NA" } { print }` to `{ print $n }`, i.e. it'd be:

```
$ awk -v col='def' -F, 'NR==1{for (n=1; n<=NF; n++) if ($n == col) break} {print $n}' file
def
a
b
c
d
gh
```

The code in your question that you said was to print one column (I added some white space to make it easier to read):

```
awk -F, '
    NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /def/) f[n++]=i }
    { for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf "%s%s", i?" ":"", $f[i]; print"" }
'
```

would actually be for printing **multiple** columns that each **contain** `def` in their name, not for printing one column that is named **exactly** `def` but better code for that would be:

```
awk -F, '
    NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /def/) f[++n]=i }
    { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n ? OFS : ORS) }
'
```

because with THAT code you're using OFS rather than hard-coding the value `" "` you hope it will have, your array `f[]` starts at 1 instead of 0, like all generated awk arrays do and all manually created arrays should, and you don't need an additional `print` at the end to add the ORS.

Answer (score -5):

```
col_num=$(awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /def/){print i }}}' content.txt)
awk -F "," -v col_num="$col_num"  'NR>1{$col_num="NA"}1' content.txt

output
abc,def,ghi
1 NA zeta
2 NA beta
3 NA ceta
4 NA xaq
5 NA lpa
```

Comment: It seems to me that 1) If more than one column matches the `def` pattern (e.g. `def1`, `def2` etc.), thiss will likely fail. 2) The output seems to remove the comma delimiters. 3) The two `awk` calls can be merged into a single call.